# Adobe Air stagewebview not using useNative browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, stagewebview

Hi I am creating a desktop flex application with a stagewebview that will not use the native browser instead of the old webkit. The [documentation says to specify `useNative`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html#StageWebView()) as true in the first parameter like below. Anyone have an idea?

I am building on windows with Air 17 and Flash Builder. The user agent is always:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/17.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       applicationComplete="stageTest(event)" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import flash.geom.Rectangle;
            import flash.media.StageWebView;

            private var webView:StageWebView;

            public function stageTest(e:*) {

                webView = new StageWebView(true);

                stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
                stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

                webView.stage = this.stage;
                webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );
                webView.loadURL( "http://whatsmyuseragent.com/" );

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: What OS are you using this on?

Comment: Also, what `swf-version` are you specifying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an [Adobe forum post](https://forums.adobe.com/message/6451137)

> The documentation says AIR 2.5+, because StageWebView, and thefore the constructor, was added in AIR 2.5, but useNative was added in AIR 3.9 I think

If you specify `swf-version 19` or higher, you'll see the native browser being used.

<sub>n.b. the forum post mentions swf-version 22, but testing shows that version 18 vs. 19 is when this behavior changes.</sub>

Comment: champion @Brian `swf-version` was my issue.